# ¿Cómo consultar a la base de datos en angularjs y php services?

Tags: php, angularjs, mysqli

necesito hacer una consulta a una base de datos.
Pensé que podía integrar php con una consulta simple pero aún así no me deja. ¿Cómo lo hice? aquí les dejo el código:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.area_name }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("services.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

y otro archivo llamado services.php

```
<?php

include('include/_setting.php');

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_server, $db_user, $db_passwd, $db_name);

if(isset($_POST['service'])){
  //UPDATE
  //INSERT
  //DELETE
}

if(isset($_GET['service'])){ 

    if($_GET['service'] == "getArea"){ 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM ayudantee.area";
            $ret = $mysqli->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
              die(json_encode($ret,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));  
    }

}

function getArea(){
    $ret = array();
    try {
        $query = "SELECT area_name FROM ayudantee.area";
        $ret = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }catch (Exception $err){
        var_dump($err);
    }
    return $ret;
}

?>
```

Comment: Y cual es tu error?

Comment: @vdjkelly, solo consulta SQL no muestra tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que el error es que no estas enviando la variable `service`. Intenta hacer esto:

```
$http.get("services.php", {
  data: {
    service: 'getArea'
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  $scope.names = response.data.records;
});
```

Comment: no nada, no consulta. :(

Comment: Podrías agregar en tu pregunta la respuesta que recibes de `services.php`?

Comment: Sii eso, como hace?

Comment: Justo debajo de tu respuesta tenes un botón que dice [`editar`](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/34813/edit)

Answer (score 0):

**Primero**, buscas el parametro `service` que venga por parametro, NO LO ENVIAS

```
if (isset($_GET['service'])) {

    if ($_GET['service'] == "getArea") {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ayudantee.area";
        $ret = $mysqli - > query($query) - > fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        die(json_encode($ret, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    }

}
```

**Segundo** , si es que lo envias, como en la respuesta de @MarcosGallardo, tampoco va a hacer nada porque no retornas nada. Pon

```
if ($_GET['service'] == "getArea") {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ayudantee.area";
    $ret = $mysqli - > query($query) - > fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        die(json_encode($ret, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    echo $ret;
}
```

**Tercero**, si es que NO tienes que enviarlo, llama a la funcion `getArea()`

```
if(isset($_GET['service'])){ 

    if($_GET['service'] == "getArea"){ 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM ayudantee.area";
            $ret = $mysqli->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
              die(json_encode($ret,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));  
    }

}else{
    echo getArea();
}
```